# mpld3 is not showing graph in Colab

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, mpld3

I'm working in `google colab` and using `mpld3` to plot graphs. Everything was working fine till last time but now `colab` is not showing graphs when I use `mpld3`. I get a graph when I simply use `pyplot` and don't use `mpld3`. Any idea what might be the issue?

When I do

```
%matplotlib inline
import mpld3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mpld3.enable_notebook()

plt.plot(range(10))
plt.show()
```

I've also tried `mpld3.display()` instead of `plt.show()`, but that also doesn't seem to work.

I don't get any output. Output cell is empty.

Comment: I'm not that experienced with matplotlib but don't you need to use  `plt.show()` to output the plot?

Comment: In `colab` or `jupyter-notebook`, you don't need it but I also tried it. I'll edit the question to remove any ambiguity.

Comment: Have you solved it? Not working for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Try `!python -m pip install "git+https://github.com/javadba/mpld3@display_fix"`

via https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KGzHsF7i3vQ49XxV7R31nsRZxhOGATr4#scrollTo=bcyd5ZmFMy5v